# Laravel how to include a partial in the base controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel

In my laravel application I am using a `Base_Controller` class and then extend this class in other controller.

In my app there is a variable which I need to use in all my controller and templates.

This is why I tried to use in my base controller.

`$this->layout->myVar = 'stuff'`

But when I try use `$myVar` in my view I am getting an error:
`Creating default object from empty value`

My base class constructor is something like this:

```
public function __constructor()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->layout->menu = 'stuff';
}
```

Does anyone have any idea on what is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You must have `$this->layout` defined in your controller class or else `$this->layout` must be assigned an instance of `View::make()`.

`$this->layout->menu` may also require having the `@section('menu') @endsection` in it.